# .htaccess routing to Node App

Tags: node.js, apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm using a shared hosting service that always has Apache web server running, so I can't run my Node.js application directly on port 80. Instead, as I've been told by my host, I need to use `.htaccess` to redirect incoming requests to my Node.js app, which is currently running on port 50000. Here's the `.htaccess` file they told me to use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:50000 [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:50000/$1 [P,L]
```

This works well enough, except that when I try to go to `mydomain.com`, the Node app is seeing a request for `/index.php`. The tech support for my host seems to be as confused as I am. If I go to `mydomain.com/test` then Node.js app sees `/test`, so Apache seems to only be adding `index.php` on the root URL. Could this be an Apache caching issue from someone accessing the URL prior to the `.htaccess` file and Node.js app being set up?

---

**UPDATE**

At this point, no one seems to have a clue what is going on, so I'm just going to add an 'index.php' route to my Node app. Thanks to everyone who took a look and tried to help out.

Comment: Can you add a VirtualHost for your Node app to your httpd.conf?

Comment: No, it's shared hosting, so I don't have access

Answer (score 3):

You might have `DirectoryIndex` set up for `index.php` in `apache conf` file which may be the reason you are getting `index.php` automatically, what you can do is to set `DirectoryIndex` to some filename which may not exist or if it is apache 2.4 use `DirectoryIndex disabled` in your `.htaccess`.

Comment: Yea, I assumed it was due to the DirectoryIndex and after changing it to something else, that was confirmed, but I don't seem to be able to disable it. Probably not running 2.4.

Comment: I put `DirectoryIndex disabled` in my `.htaccess` and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually what you are going to want to put in your /public_html directory

In the .htaccess file in the code below you will see

```
http://127.0.0.1:50000
```

(50000) is the port you are sending it too. There are 2 spots where you make that update.

Also update the example.com

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]

DirectoryIndex disabled

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:50000 / [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:50000 /$1 [P,L]
```

This is a specific configuration for an apache server with nodejs.

Comment: @nistm  Please clarify something. Are you saying to put this script code into **both** the example.com and public_html directory's .htaccess file ?  I assume that in the redirect URL one can write *localhost* in place of *127.0.0.1* ?

Comment: **DirectoryIndex disabled** blocks all access to the website files via a browser. That will make it impossible to use the app.