# nodejs express giving 404 error on index route

Tags: node.js, express

I'm deploying my nodejs project on a website and the problem is that when we set it up on cpanel a run it shows 404 error when trying to access index route all other routes are ok and without any problem. I'm running it using "npm start" and port is 3005 and when I access it through the website ip and port it seems to be no problem at all but when I access it with website domain it shows 404 error on index route also on localhost everything is working fine

app.js

```js
import debug = require('debug');
import express = require('express');
import path = require('path');
import routes from './routes/index';
import test1 from './routes/test1';
import test2 from './routes/test2';
import test3 from './routes/test3';
import helmet = require('helmet');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var FileStore = require('session-file-store')(session);
var device = require('express-device');
var compression = require('compression');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(device.capture({ parseUserAgent: true }));
app.use(express.json());       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // to support URL-encoded bodies
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(compression());
app.use(helmet());
app.set('trust proxy', 1);
app.use(session({
    secret: 'test',
    resave: false,
    store: new FileStore(),
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        secure: false, //for https
        maxAge: 60000
    }
}));
Array.prototype.unique = function () {
    var a = this.concat();
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < a.length; ++j) {
            if (a[i].id === a[j].id)
                a.splice(j--, 1);
        }
    }

    return a;
};
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes); // 404 error for this line
app.use('/test1', test1);
app.use('/test2', test2);
app.use('/test3', test3);
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err['status'] = 404;
    next(err);
});
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const oldRedirect = res.redirect;
    res.redirect = function (...args) {
        if (req.session) {
            req.session.save(() => Reflect.apply(oldRedirect, this, args));
        } else {
            Reflect.apply(oldRedirect, this, args);
        }
    }
});
// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use((err: any, req, res, next) => {
        res.status(err['status'] || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use((err: any, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3005);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

index.js

```js
import express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    if (req.session.test) {
        return res.redirect('/test1');
    } else if (req.session.test2) {
        return res.redirect('/test2');
    } else {
        return res.redirect('/test3');
    }
});

export default router;
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node app"
  },
```

htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:3005%{REQUEST_URI} [P]

<FilesMatch "\.(png)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php70” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php70 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

404 not found. I expected the index to redirect to test1 or test2 or test3 but I get a 404 error on the index. I can access test1 or test2 or test 3 by URL

the error code that I'm receiving :

```
Error: Not Found
    at /mnt/volume-sfo2-04/test/public_html/test/app.js:78:15
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/mnt/volume-sfo2-04/test/public_html/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/mnt/volume-sfo2-04/test/public_html/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /mnt/volume-sfo2-04/test/public_html/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/mnt/volume-sfo2-04/test/public_html/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/mnt/volume-sfo2-04/test/public_html/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /mnt/volume-sfo2-04/test/public_html/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:15
    at next (/mnt/volume-sfo2-04/test/public_html/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:260:14)
    at Function.handle (/mnt/volume-sfo2-04/test/public_html/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/mnt/volume-sfo2-04/test/public_html/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems to be a problem with DirectoryIndex that it is looking for an index.php file in the directory of the nodejs for app.use("/"). thanks to this question my problem is solved [htaccess-routing-to-node-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50663307/htaccess-routing-to-node-app)